# How could convert a cairo_surface_t png to jpeg format

Tags: c++, c, png, jpeg, cairo

In the context of a semi-graphical application, I am managing `cairo_surface_t` objects and saving them through the `cairo_surface_write_to_png()` interface.

However, trying to get smaller files, I would prefer to save them in `jpeg` format and maybe to compress them through some such as `jpeglib`.

I wonder if there is any efficient way for transforming the `cairo_surface_t` object to one that could be saved in `jpeg` format. By "efficient" I want to say at least without first saving in `png` and after transforming it to `jpeg`.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Why do you need smaller files? What is the difference, have you considered that, how much difference there is? and whether or not it is worth it?

Comment: @iharob Thanks for you interest. Yes, eventually, I need smaller files because they are sent through a network with high jitter and low bandwidth and I could lose some resolution without serious effects